# Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, keyts(2739)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-context

I am trying to use the context API with TypeScript in NextJS but I keep getting this TS error that is not clear and I do not understand.

Below is the code sample `appContext.ts` where I get this error around the `return` statement.

```
import React, {
    createContext,
    useReducer,
    Dispatch,
    FunctionComponent,
} from 'react';
import { AppActions } from '../actions';
import appReducer from '../reducers/appReducer';
import { AppState, initialState } from '../state';


export const AppContext = createContext<{
    state: AppState;
    dispatch: Dispatch<AppActions>;
}>({
    state: initialState,
    dispatch: () => undefined,
});

const AppContextProvider: FunctionComponent = ({ children }): JSX.Element => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(appReducer, initialState);

    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
            {children}
        </AppContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default AppContextProvider;
```

Please help.

Comment: I'm on my phone and can't test your code, but my guess is your return typing is too verbose. Try either removing the `FunctionComponent` or `JSX.Element`.

Comment: @AnthonyMa Did that but it error still persist

Comment: Please produce a minimal reproducible example, you can do that on TS Playground or CodeSandbox.